# Image Preloader fails to show up on android

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova

i've built an app with jquery and compiled with phonegap build. there's also a website version for it. When a user submit data there's a preloader that show up that something its working in the background which works fine on the website. But in the app the preloader fails to work.

```
<span style="width: 480px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 30px;"><img src="imgs/loader.gif" alt="" name="fpass" id="fpass" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 30px; visibility: hidden;" /></span>
```

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#form3').submit(function() {
    $('#fpass').css('visibility', 'visible');
    return true;
});

 </script>
```

HTML

```
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="">
<table width="436" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Enter your Email Address</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="email3"></label>
          <input name="email3" type="email" id="email3" size="40" required="required"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;
            <button>Submit</button>
          <div align="center"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span style="width: 480px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 30px;"><img src="imgs/loader.gif" alt="" name="fpass" id="fpass" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 30px; visibility: hidden;" /></span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
</form>
```

Comment: i think the problem is the submit event.Try change into click event

Answer (score 0):

you can use `event.preventDefault()`

```
$('#form3').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#fpass').css('visibility', 'visible');
    return true;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9q76jeu2/

Comment: using e.preventDefault(); stops the form from submitting